# Rails axlsx gem. Insert mathematical equation to worksheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-excel, axlsx

Another thing that I can't find in axlsx docs.

I need to add mathematical equation to my entire worksheet and I wonder how can I achieve this using [`axlsx`](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) gam.

Here screenshot of what I want to create.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the repo's issues? Or talk to the author?

Comment: No. I just asked here.

Comment: Go check those resources first, you might get more luck there.